# Sound Problem in ubuntu startup

Tags: ubuntu, boot, audio

When Ubuntu boots first time, no sound comes out of speakers. But when I insert any headphone the sound is OK. also when I insert headphone first time and eject it from laptop then sound comes fine from speakers. It means there is some thing wrong in boot settings. But unfortunately I don't know how to resolve this problem.

I have tried this:

```
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ sudo service pulseaudio restart 
[sudo] password for hamad: 
pulseaudio stop/waiting
pulseaudio start/running, process 3093
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ sudo service pulseaudio restart 
pulseaudio stop/waiting
pulseaudio start/running, process 3164
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ pulseaudio -k
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ sleep 2
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ pulseaudio
;
^Chamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ pulseaudio;
^Chamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ pulseaudio -k sleep 2 pulseaudio 
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Too many arguments.
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ pulseaudio -k sleep 2
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Too many arguments.
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ sleep 2
hamad@hamad-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ pulseaudio
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: [No sound by speaker in ubuntu 12.04, only by headphones (re installing, updating and in liveUSB without sound)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/322025/no-sound-by-speaker-in-ubuntu-12-04-only-by-headphones-re-installing-updating). Found dozens of links on Google in case your problem is different.

Comment: It seems like your laptop is assuming that the headphone is attached by default, and hence it is routing all the audio to headphone even when it is not attached. And when you insert the headphone and take it out, it realizes that the headphone is unplugged and hence the speakers get activated. There is one thing you can try: `pulseaudio -k; sleep 2; pulseaudio; `. This will restart the pulseaudio server. Tell me if this fixes the problem.

Comment: @shivams thanks for understanding my problem! I have updated my question with you suggestion.I have tried that but didn't get success.